# How to install UpSetPlot on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, upsetplot

I am using google colab for python programming.
however, the package UpSetPlot was not installed. I tried using the command:

```
!pip install UpSetPlot
```

but the following error appears:

```
Collecting UpSetPlot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/11/5cc8a0ebaf4f3a9a8e02cd3a9a13806eaebfc1d2ffb4a40031bdc83ad1be/UpSetPlot-0.5.0.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in versions after `0.4.1` of `upsetplot` which may be related to the version of Python that is used in Colab.

Try this in a Colab cell.

```
!pip install upsetplot==0.4.1
```